# C# Accessing Flash COM Object using WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, flash, webbrowser-control

I have a HTML page that contains a flash file and some a JavaScript function that returns the object of the flash file.

So far I can call the JavaScript function from C# and have it return an Object, but I want to cast it as AxShockwaveFlash and access the COM Object directly from C#.

I have seen this done with Windows Media Player imbedded in the a HTML page, but it doesn't seem to work with flash.

`<script type="text/JavaScript"> function GetWMP() { return(testing); } <script>`

<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="857" height="480" id="testing">

<param name="movie" value="test.swf" />

<param name="quality" value="high" />

<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />

<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />

<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />

</object>

Below is my C# code which returns the object.

`object o = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("ReturnFlash");`

AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash flash = (AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash)o;

When I try to cast the Object to AxShockwaveFlash it fails, but I have seen it work casting the object to WindowsMediaPlayer.

I tried to find if AxShockwaveFlash supports QueryInterface calls, as per the error message but Google returned nothing of value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AxShockwaveFlash is an auto-generated Windows Forms control, created by aximp.exe.  So you can put it on a form.  That object you got is not that control.  You can only cast to the interface exposed by the interop wrapper, which should be ShockwaveFlashObjects.ShockwaveFlash.

Comment: Thanks. Casting the object to ShockwaveFlash works great, and while it exposed the events (FlashCall, OnReadyStateChange, etc) they don't seem to be firing. Any idea why?

Comment: Update: It seems that it doesn't handle the events because Flash Com Object never issues them, since it's in a browser and expects a JavaScript function to be called. Oh well.